# MariaDB create database relational tables

Tags: php, mariadb

I created 2 tables as follows:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    first_name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL
    date_created VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    date_modified VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
)";
```

This table was created successfully.

I tried to create a 2nd table as follows:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE users_performance (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_id INT(11) REFERENCES users(id) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    performance text NOT NULL
)";
```

This failed with following error:

> Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, performance text NOT NULL )' at line 3

Now the error line is:

> user_id INT(11) REFERENCES users(id) UNIQUE NOT NULL

I have scratched through Maria DB manual but can't quickly get a solution.
I know this syntax works fine on postgresql. Why is it not working on mysqli
I prefer to create 2 separate tables for future changes, etc.
Thanks

Comment: Not null belongs before references

Comment: You're missing a comma at the end of the `email` line in the first table.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that you are using MariaDB 10.5 or later. Inline foreign keys are not implemented in older versions of MariaDB.

Then, move the `UNIQUE NOT NULL` before the foreign key option. The order of column options is important.

Also, make sure the data type of the foreign key column is the same as the column it references. In this case, you need to make it `INT UNSIGNED`. The "length" option `(11)` doesn't matter, and you can omit it.

```
user_id INT UNSIGNED UNIQUE NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=54964388cd0d880169c0332934c13b3d

Comment: before 10.5, simply separate the foreign key reference: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=129c00c5658910bd1b960dcf78d0646c

Comment: @ysth, Yes, that's correct. But the data types must still match.

Comment: @BillKarwin response fits perfectly and works fine. Key gain is the STRICT sequencial flow of the column options